# how do I create a new row every time there are 4 data arrays?

Tags: php

i when want every 4 data array to create new row but it become messy after output first row

```php
<?php
$data = [21, 231, 12121, 3332, 444444, 2212, 1, 234, 5523, 312];

$count = count($data);
$length = max(array_map('strlen', $data));

foreach ($data as $v) {
    $diff = $length - strlen($v);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $diff; $i++) {
        echo '*';
        
    }
    
    if (($i+1) % 3 == 0) {
      echo $v . '</br>';
    } else {
      echo $v;
    }
    
    echo '|';
}

?>
```

my output currently :
[output-currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SxYT.png)

i hope my output this :

[hope output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ6Fw.png)

Comment: For your consideration: https://3v4l.org/pTDcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
```

to get the index of the iteration over `$data`.

then change the condition to:

```
if (($k+1) % 4 == 0) {
```

Here's a demo:
https://3v4l.org/EZcJ9

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)